# how to extract first two characters of second word from a column in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, extract

I wanted to extract the first two characters of the second word in a column on excel. That was my goal.

I have already found the solution and I would like to share with you the solution because I searched on the net and I had not found.

Here is the formula used:

```
=UPPER(LEFT((RIGHT(**G2**;LEN(**G2**)-FIND(" ";**G2**)));2))
```

where G2 is the column index on excel and UPPER to put everything in uppercase.

```
=UPPER( CONCATENATE( (LEFT(G3; 3)); (LEFT((RIGHT(G3;LEN(G3)-FIND(" ";G3)));2))) )
```

| Column | first two characters (from second word) |
| --- | --- |
| Accipiter gentilis | GE |
| Actitis hypoleucos | HY |

In addition, I also want to add that to extract the first two characters of each word (among the two) and concatenate them just apply the following formula:

```
=UPPER( CONCATENATE( (LEFT(G3; 2 )); (LEFT((RIGHT(G3;LEN(G3)-FIND(" ";G3)));2))) )
```

Result:

| column | first tow caracters (from first and second word) |
| --- | --- |
| Accipiter gentilis | ACGE |
| Actitis hypoleucos | ACHY |

If there are other supplements or other formulas that work the same way

Answer (score 1):

To get first 2 letters from second word:

```
=INDEX(LEFT(TEXTSPLIT(UPPER(A1)," "),2),2)
```

To get first 2 letters from every word:

```
=CONCAT(LEFT(TEXTSPLIT(UPPER(A4)," "),2))
```

To get first 2 letters from first 2 words:

```
=CONCAT(INDEX((LEFT(TEXTSPLIT(UPPER(A7)," "),2)),SEQUENCE(2)))
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the explanations of your post it looks like you are working with the scientific names of `Northern goshawk` & `Common sandpiper` may be you have more and along with those names there could be some other features of the birds. Therefore for your first question, you could try using `TEXTAFTER()` and for the second one you can use `TAKE()` & `TEXTSPLIT()`

[image]

---

**First Two Characters (From Second Word)**

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=UPPER(LEFT(TEXTAFTER(A2," "),2))
```

Or,

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=UPPER(LEFT(TEXTAFTER(A2:A3," "),2))
```

---

**First Two Characters From Every Word**

• Formula used in cell `B8`

```
=CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(TEXTSPLIT(A8," "),2)))
```

---

**First Two Characters (From First And Second Word)**

• Formula used in cell `B14`

```
=CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A14,," "),2),2)))
```

---

Since I am not sure about your Excel Version, here are few alternative versions, you could try:

[image]

---

**First Two Characters (From Second Word)**

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=UPPER(LEFT(FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b[2]"),2))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=UPPER(LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",REPT(" ",100)),100,100)),2))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=UPPER(LEFT(REPLACE(A2,1,FIND(" ",A2),""),2))
```

---

**First Two Characters From Every Word**

• Formula used in cell `B10`

```
=CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A10," ","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b"),2)))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `C10`

```
=CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A10," ",REPT(" ",100)),COLUMN($A$1:$Z$1)*100-99,100)),2)))
```

---

**First Two Characters (From First And Second Word)**

• Formula used in cell `B17`

```
=CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A17," ","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b[position()<3]"),2)))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `C17`

```
=CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A17," ",REPT(" ",100)),COLUMN($A$1:$B$1)*100-99,100)),2)))
```

---